# Understanding a driver manual

Tags: i2c, driver

I'm a bit confused about [this](https://picolas.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/BFPS-VRHSP_02_Manual_Rev1905.pdf) driver manual about its communication protocol. I want to turn on and off the driver by its I2C interface using its "I/O Connector" with a microcontroller board. The driver also have "RS-232 Connector" for text based PC control.

Where I'm confused is that the driver mentions its own protocol called "The PicoLAS Protocol" but I couldn't figure out which connector(interface) this protocol use. Does their protocol use the I2C interface or the RS232?

Comment: It says connected to a PC so I think RS-232.

Comment: I want to enable or disable this driver by I2C interface but I can only see LSTAT register. And there is a section called "Description of the LSTAT Register" but it doesn't seem those bits enable or disable the driver. It also writes "The internal generator is deactivated by value 0 Hz. Should I use Reprate to stop output?

Answer (score 3):

The data sheet is clear on this.

On the I2C interface it looks like any register based I2C device with 32-bit wide data registers.

On the RS-232 interface, you can either use a text based protocol or the binary PicoLAS protocol, but you must choose it by sending a command to select the protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. Just one more thing with I2C and driver's internal trigger generator. I want to enable or disable this driver by I2C interface but I can only see LSTAT register. And there is a section called "Description of the LSTAT Register" but it doesn't seem those bits enable or disable the driver. It also writes "The internal generator is deactivated by value 0 Hz. Should I use Reprate to stop output?